# Finding intersection line question without the $z$ axis.

Tags: vectors

What is the intersection line of these two planes:

$$ P_1 : 3x+4y+7z=5$$

$$P_2: 2x-5y=8$$

I will first multiply one by $4$ and the second by $5$ just to get rid of $y$:

$$15x+20y+35z -25 = 0$$
$$8x-20y-32=0$$

Adding those two, in order to get the intersection plane:

$$23x + 35z -57 = 0$$

Now we want to find $2$ points in order to get the line:

So first let's substitute a random value, say $x=1$ :

$$23 +35z -57 = 0$$

$$z = \frac{34}{35}$$

Now checking what is $y$ by checking it on our plane:

$$ 3 \cdot 1 + 4y + \frac{7 \cdot 34}{35} -5 = 0 $$
$$y = - \frac{6}{5}$$

So we have one point:
$$ (1, - \frac{6}{5}, \frac{34}{35} )$$

Now for the second point:

I substituted : $ z = 0$

$$23x = 57 \Rightarrow x = \frac{57}{23}$$

And to get $y$ I subs. it in the inters. plane:

$$3 \cdot \frac{57}{23} + 4y - 5 =0 $$

$$y = 5 - 3 \cdot \frac{53}{23} = - \frac{14}{23}$$

And so we have our second point:

$$(\frac{57}{23} , - \frac{14}{23}, 0)$$

We will now take the difference to get the direction vector:

$$ ( \frac{57}{23} - 1 , - \frac{14}{23} + \frac{6}{5} , - \frac{34}{35})  = (\frac{34}{23}, \frac{68}{115}, - \frac{34}{35})$$

To get that our intersection line is (starting at the first or second point we found) and the "direction" vector :

$$(1 , - \frac{6}{5}, \frac{34}{35}) + t ( \frac{34}{23}, \frac{68}{115}, -\frac{34}{35})$$

This is not the right answer as GeoGebra says:

[image]

This is clearly not the intersecting line...

I would appreciate your help, I really checked myself dozens of times... thanks!

Comment: What you got is on $P_1$ and $P_2$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- First, find the normal vectors $n_1$ and $n_2$ of both planes (that are the vectors formed from the coefficients).
- Second, find the direction vector $d$ of the intersection line ($d = n_1 \times n_2$)
- Third, find any point that lies on both planes (*hint for this step*: set $z=0$, for example, and solve the system for $x$ and $y$)

After all, you will have a direction vector of a line and a point lying on this line.

Let me know if you can take it from here.

Comment: Why is the direction vector $\vec{n_1} \times \vec{n_2}$ ? I don't remember we said that in class, can I use it?

Comment: @StackOMeow By definition of the cross product. For more information: http://www.math.uwaterloo.ca/~jmckinno/Math106/Week3/Lecture1s.pdf

Comment: When I solve the system after plugging $z=0$ I get: $x = \frac{57}{23} \text{and} ~~ y = - \frac{56}{23}$

And the line $(\frac{57}{23}, -\frac{56}{23} , 0) + t (35, 14,-23) $ is not the intersecting line by geogebra..

Comment: @StackOMeow Are you sure you got all calculation right?

Comment: I've checked myself again and it seems right

Comment: @StackOMeow please see my calculation. I think you made an error and did not divide by 4 to get y. Also you can do by just plugging in z = t instead of these two steps.

Answer (score 1):

$P_1 : 3x+4y+7z=5$

$P_2: 2x-5y=8$

You can either find the cross-product of the normal vector of the two planes and a point on the intersection to find the equation of the line or you can do as below -

For $z = t$,

$3x+4y=5-7t$ and $2x-5y=8$

Equating the two, you get -

$x = \dfrac {57-35t}{23}, y = \dfrac{-14-14t}{23}, z = t$

The parameterized equation of the line will be,

$(x,y,z) = (\dfrac{57}{23},-\dfrac {14}{23}, 0)+(-35,-14,23)t$

If you do the cross product of the normal vectors of the planes, again you will get the direction vector of the line as ($-35,-14,23)$. You can find a point on the line assuming $z = 0$. You get the same equation.

Comment: The cross product gave me the negated vector $(35,14,-23)$ does that matter?

Comment: @StackOMeow No, it doesn't. My answer also leads to this result... I think you got the $y$ coordinate wrong when commented on my answer.

Comment: No it doesn't matter for the equation of the line.